# Send multiple variables to server jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, post

How can I send multiple variables to external server using `jQuery.ajax`. I need to send values from variables to external PHP file which updates mySQL. This is the code I use right now:

Javascript:

```
var number= localStorage.getItem("number")
var coords = {lat: "", lon: ""};

window.onload = function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else{
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    coords.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    coords.lon = position.coords.longitude;

    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + coords.lat + "<br />Longitude: " + coords.lon;  
}

function sendToServer() {
    // here you can reuse the object to send to a server
    alert(coords.lon);
}

function Updatelocation() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "location.php",
        data: 'x='+coords.lon, 'y='coords.lat, 'number'=number
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Record successfully updated");
        }
    });
}
```

and `location.php`:

```
<?php
  include 'config.php';

  // database connection
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

  // new data

  $x = @$_POST['x'];
  $y = @$_POST['y'];
  $num = @$_POST['num'];
  // query
  $sql = "update table set 
  x=? , 
  y=? 
  where num='?'";
  $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array($x, $y, $num));
?>
```

Comment: Please learn how to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier for you and others to understand at a glance.

Comment: Your inserting a questionmark instead of a variable, see my answer

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
data: 'x='+coords.lon, 'y='coords.lat, 'number'=number
```

to

```
data: 'x='+coords.lon+'&y='+coords.lat+'&number='+number;
```

By the way, in your PHP-file you are refering to `id`, but you don't send a variable called that.

Comment: I changed the PHP-file. But is there something else wrong with my code, because this doesn't work?

Comment: Change num to number in the php file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use JSON:

```
data = {
  x: cords.lon,
  y: cords.lat,
  number:number
}
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "location.php",
    data: 'data='+JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Record successfully updated");
    }
});
```

location.php

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';

    // database connection
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

    // data from javascript
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

    // query
    $sql = "update table set 
    x=? , 
    y=? 
    where num='?'";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($data->{'x'}, $data->{'y'}, $data->{'number'}));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability I'd use a struct:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "location.php",
    data: {
        x       : coords.lon,
        y       : coords.lat,
        num     : number
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Record successfully updated");
    }
});
```

also: in your php you use "num" not "number"

**EDIT**: and remove the quotes around your last question mark

```
$sql = "update table set 
x=? , 
y=? 
where num=?";
```

instead of

```
$sql = "update table set 
x=? , 
y=? 
where num='?'";
```